# Broadcast SignalR message to all clients in Orleans

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, orleans

Regular `SignalR` has ability to broadcast messages without filtering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

```
Clients.All.Send()
```

This would broadcast message to all clients connected to `Hub`. Meanwhile, `SignalR.Orleans` seems to provide only messages to specific group.

```
HubContext.Group(groupName).Send()
```

https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans/blob/master/samples/ChatSample/Grains/UserNotificationGrain.cs

**Question**

Is there a way to broadcast SignalR message in Orleans without filtering and creating groups?

[image]

Comment: Just `HubContext.All.Send()` should work fine. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans/blob/c79a3464960c0ac0ad03163ba41f85677de44bd0/src/SignalR.Orleans/OrleansHubLifetimeManager.cs#L160) and as you can see they broadcast message to all hubs in all nodes with a stream.

Comment: @AliZeinali `HubContext` doesn't seem to have this method. Attached picture. The link that you provided seems to extend Silo's methods, not sure if I can and should call Silo from the grain...

Comment: which version of .NET are you using? That `HubContext` you used is not part of SignalR because SignalR [HubContext](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/Internal/HubContext.cs) is internal an it's not available public

Comment: you should use [IHubContext<MessageHub>](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dbf84eaa5a8f79947647ad64a785d39e7cd23afe/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/IHubContext.cs#L14) which has a `Clients` property and then you can access [`All`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dbf84eaa5a8f79947647ad64a785d39e7cd23afe/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/IHubClients%60T.cs#L18)

Comment: @AliZeinali The link to `HubContext` implementation was really useful. I can access `Clients.All` now. Not sure that regular `SignalR` will work properly without Orleans backplane, e.g. may have duplicated messages from several silos, but now I can experiment with it. Feel free to post link to `IHubContext` as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `IHubContext<THub>.Clients.All` and it would work fine.

The `SignalR.Orleans` package implement its own `HublifetimeManager`([github](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans/blob/master/src/SignalR.Orleans/OrleansHubLifetimeManager.cs)) and when you config SignalR to `AddOrleans` it would replace the `DefaultHublifetimeManager`([github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/DefaultHubLifetimeManager.cs)) with its own implementation so any usage of `IHubContext<THub>.Clients` or `IHubContext<THub>.Groups` would use Orleans implementation of `HublifetimeManager`.
So when you use `IHubContext<THub>.Clients.All` it would use `OrleansHubLifetimeManager<THub>` to send message and in [detail](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans/blob/c79a3464960c0ac0ad03163ba41f85677de44bd0/src/SignalR.Orleans/OrleansHubLifetimeManager.cs#L160) it would broadcast your message to all silos with help of [Orleans Streams](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/streaming/index.html)

**Just For More Info:**
[`IHubContext<THub>.Clients.All`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/348b810d286fd2258aa763d6eda667a83ff972dc/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/Internal/HubClients.cs#L15) return an  instance of [`AllClientProxy<THub>`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/348b810d286fd2258aa763d6eda667a83ff972dc/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/Internal/Proxies.cs#L97) which it's using `HublifetimeManager.SendAllAsync` method to send messages